# How can I push multiple files using ADB?

Tags: adb

I had pulled the whole `/data/` directory onto `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\DATA`, and now would like to put it back in. How would I push all the files in `\DATA` to `/data/` on my phone? I certainly could do it one at a time, but that is very slow.

Wildcards do not work, such as:

> adb push * /data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To push all the files back in /data/ just use:

```
adb push %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\DATA /data/
```

This will push all the files in the %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\DATA folder in the destination specified.

Comment: You forgot dot after DATA, it should be DATA\.

Comment: how it works? DATA. ?